# What are the time and space complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity

What is the time and space complexity of this algorithm and can it be improved (how)? It generates random 4 digit even number and the adjacent 2 digits must be different.

```
def random_digits():
    import random
    num = ''
    for i in range(0, 4):
        curr = random.randint(0,9)
        print('curr', curr)
        if (i != (i+1)):
            if (i == 3 and (curr % 2 != 0)):
                curr = curr - 1
            num += str(curr)
```

Comment: I don't know python, but what is the meaning of `if (i != (i+1))`? It looks like you're wondering if 3!=4, which is always true. I don't see the 'adjacent 2 digits must be different' part anywhere.

Comment: This question has been downvoted and closed for multiple reasons: (a) possibly broken code, (b) primarily seeking an explanation of code, (c) unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer regarding your question:

- Imports should be at the top;
- You don't need to import all of *random* just for *randint*:
  Use `from random import randint`
- You don't need parentheses in `if (i != (i+1))` and `if (i == 3 and (curr % 2 != 0))`
- Instead of `curr = curr - 1`, use `curr -= 1`
- If `range()` is called with a single parameter *n*, the first value will automatically be 0, so there's no need to explicitly call `range(0, n)`.